# Setting up meme bot with Twilio

Tags: twilio

Im just starting to learn python, so I need some help here. I found this website called Twilio. One of its features is you can program a custom SMS bot. Me and my close friends have a group text. Often, we like to share memes with each other. So my idea is we can add my Twilio number to the group chat, and set up Twilio so when someone says, "Memes please", it will automatically get 5 memes from a website (like http://cleanmemes.com/ or somthing similar), and send them.

If its hard to grab memes from a meme website (wich im assuming it is), its fine if i have to provide links to memes. Or mabe i can put a folder on my server filled with memes? What do you think would be easiest?

Can someone give me some pointers?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/07/building-a-group-messaging-app-with-meteor-mongodb-and-twilio.html) are a [couple](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/04/rewind-build-a-group-messaging-application-with-asp-net-mvc.html) examples of handling group messaging with Twilio. These examples are not in Python but you can take a look at the logic to decide what might work best in your scenario and then use the [Python helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python) to create your own app.

As far as handling memes, you might want to consider a site that has an API - [like Giphy](https://api.giphy.com) which would make grabbing the memes a lot easier.

Let me know if this helps.